# dragging both UITableView and its containing UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have a UITableView within a UIView where the UIView is acting as a pullup view. I would like to drag the view  up and down the screen and for the view to move up with my drag.

If I am touching the UITableView part then I would like to just drag up until the UIView reaches some top limit and then for my dragging to start dragging up the UITableView.

If the UIView is at its top limit and I drag down on the UITableView then I would like the UITableView to drag down until it reaches its beginning then for the drag to transfer to the UIView, dragging that down the screen with the UITableView along with it.

Furthermore, the UITableVIew has buttons that need to continue reacting to presses so I cannot simply turn off the user interactivity of the tableview when I want.

Currently I am setting  a flag when the UIView is at its top parking position and then using the following methods in an extended UITableView class

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    CGPoint then = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView: self];
    CGPoint now = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: self];
    //CGFloat deltaY = fabs(then.y - now.y);

    if(self.contentOffset.y == 0 && now.y > then.y)
        inSlideMode_ = YES;

    if(inSlideMode_)
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else
    {
        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint then = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView: self];
    CGPoint now = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: self];
    //CGFloat deltaY = fabs(then.y - now.y);

    if(self.contentOffset.y == 0 && now.y > then.y)
        inSlideMode_ = YES;


    if (inSlideMode_)
    {
        //forwarding action:
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else
    {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}



-( void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    if(inSlideMode_)
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else
    {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }

    previousTouchY_ =UNTOUCHED_Y_POSITION;
}


    -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0)
    {
        self.scrollEnabled = NO; // if we reach the top of scrolling then should switch     tableview  into the pullup interactor
        self.inSlideMode = YES;

    }
}
```

In the UIView extended class, I am overriding the same methods to handle the dragging and also looking to see whether it is docked to top.

Currently it nearly works but when dragging the UITableView, once it reaches the bottom I need to lift finger and start dragging on it again to get the UIView to be dragged down. Any suggestions???  Thanks

Comment: Actually that sounds great as you have it. I think the user would be very surprised if the *same* gesture applied *first* to one view and *then* to another. The basic semantic rule is that *each* touch goes to *one* view.

Comment: Matt, thanks but it is not what feels quite right. I want for the two component to feel as one so that dragging continues naturally from one to another.

Comment: just noticed that the behaviour I am after is how chrome handles scrolling the code section above - ie one scrolling, once it gets to edge the scrolling continues in the next view up. Matt, perhaps I didn't explain it too well - as you can see the behaviour I want is very standard for users